# About getting rid of empty space in word count

Tags: python

I am dealing with a passage. I am required to sort the words in the passage alphabetically and then sort them by reverse frequency. When my word count function sorts the passage, it counts empty space too. I did some modification and it still counts the empty string. I am wondering if there is any other way to do it. My codes are:

```
def build_map( in_file, word_map ):

    for line in in_file:

        # Splits each line at blank space and turns it into
        # a list.
        word_list = line.split()

        for word in word_list:
            if word!='':

                # Within the word_list, we are stripping empty space
                # on both sides of each word and also stripping any
                # punctuation on both side of each word in the list.
                # Then, it turns each word to the lower case to avoid
                # counting 'THE' and 'the' as two different words.
                word = word.strip().strip(string.punctuation).lower()#program revised
                add_word( word_map, word )
```

Comment: if it's a space it's not empty, what do you mean by "empty space"?

Comment: I should say 'empty string'.

Comment: @marcadian: I think maybe he means whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

This should get you going in the right direction, you'll need to process it, probably by stripping periods and colons, and you might want to make it all lowercase anyways.

```
passage = '''I am dealing with a passage. I am required to sort the words in the passage alphabetically and then sort them by reverse frequency. When my word count function sorts the passage, it counts empty space too. I did some modification and it still counts the empty spaces. I am wondering if there is any other way to do it. My codes are:'''

words = set(passage.split())

alpha_sort = sorted(words, key=str.lower)

frequency_sort = sorted(words, key=passage.count, reverse=True)
```

Comment: My program is sorting words fine. My problem is that while counting words, the program is also counting empty strings and I don't want that. I want the program to count only words. That is why I used if word != '':, but I am still not getting the required output.

Comment: use `my_list = filter(None, my_list)`

Answer (score 0):

To filter empty strings from a list of strings, I would use:

```
my_list = filter(None, my_list)
```

Comment: Nah, the problem is somewhere else in my program. I am dealing with a dictionary. Processing the dictionary to get a list and then working on the list. So, if the dictionary has key as empty string and it is mapped to a value, then of course the list that I am making will also show the key and value. So, I think to get rid of the empty string from word count, I need to fix the dictionary. I tried your code and unfortunately, it did not work. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you're looking for [str.isspace()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.isspace)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
if word!='':
```

you should use:

```
if word.strip()!='':
```

because the first one checks for zero-length strings, and you want to eliminate the spaces which are not zero length. Stripping an only-space string will make it zero-length.